# jquery compare function and then refresh

Tags: jquery, function, compare, refresh

I have the following code which reloads the function `pollastation` every 30 sec.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    pollstation();
    setInterval(pollstation, 30000);
});
```

What I want to achieve is to make this code check every 30 sec to compare the function `pollstation`, and if the `pollstation` content is the same do not refresh, but if it is different then refresh.

I must tell you that I only know the basics of `JavaScript`.

I searched Google, and tried using the code below, but it didn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    pollstation();
   pollstation.load(pollstation + Math.random());
   var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
         pollstation.load(pollstation + Math.random());
      }, 30000);
   $.ajaxSetup({
      cache : false
   });   
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: When i add this code it did not refresh the page.
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        pollstation();
        pollstation.load(pollstation + Math.random());
       var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
            pollstation.load(pollstation + Math.random());
              }, 30000);
           $.ajaxSetup({
        cache : false
           });   
        });

Comment: It's a little worrying to see both `pollstation()` and `pollstation.load()`, ie. a function as a property of another function. This isn't necessarily invalid, but somewhat unusual. Do you really know what you're doing in this regard?

Comment: actually i don't know what a i doing. I only knew some basic skills about javascript and i assume that something like this could be work.